# How to update an existing github repo from a different computer?

Tags: git, android-studio, github, version-control

I am working on my Android project from a different computer.  After downloading Android Studio, I downloaded my project as a ZIP file and then made some changes on it through the IDE on the new computer.  I want to commit these changes to the existing repo through git but idk how to do that.  So far I couldn't find much on the internet for this specific problem.

Comment: Does you project have .git folder inside ZIP file?

Comment: no it does not....

Comment: Just `git clone` instead. Also, remember that `.git` is a hidden folder, so unless you've enabled seeing those by default, you'll need to manually find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Run `git clone https://github.com/your/repo` to clone your project on your computer. It will create a new folder containing your Android project
2. Copy your changed files in this new folder
3. You can now commit your changes from this folder
4. In android studio, open the new folder instead of the one from the .ZIP

Comment: I have the same folder in my other computer.  Will my changes in that computer reflect to this one?

Comment: No, you have to manually pull code from the repo into that computer to. use below command to pull

`git pull origin <branch-name>`

Comment: @AndrosAdrianopolos - if you have already pushed code from the folder (or if you have a .git folder in it), you have to run `git pull` to sync your changes

Comment: I've accepted and upvoted your answer.  Thank you very much.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you upvote me as well?